Publishing files to an out directory in Nextflow
I am working on an Nextflow pipelines that has several processes controlled by the main pipeline. One of my processes generates multiple or at least one folder which names are project names. I publish these folders into a pipeline's output folder. Next process generates come csv files which have prefixes the same as folder names generated in the previous steps of the pipeline. I want to publish these files inside the corresponding directories.
process COUNT{

input:
path stats_file

output:
stdout emit: result
path "*counts.csv", type: "file", emit counts

script:
bash call of a python script that takes one stats file, splits it into multiple *counts.csv files and outputs them in a format <project_name>_counts.csv
touch project_1_counts.csv
touch project_2_counts.csv
}

I have, in the out directory: out/pipeline two folders created by the previous step: out/pipeline/project_1 and out/pipeline/project_2. I want project_1_counts.csv to be saved in project_1  and project_2_counts.csv to be saved in project 2 direcrtory.
I know that I have to write a publishDir directive before input/output sections, but I don't know how to write one that will be matching the script output files and the corresponding folders.

You can use the saveAs option with the publishDir directive for this:

saveAs
A closure which, given the name of the file being published,
returns the actual file name or a full path where the file is required
to be stored. This can be used to rename or change the destination
directory of the published files dynamically by using a custom
strategy. Return the value null from the closure to not publish a
file. This is useful when the process has multiple output files, but
you want to publish only some of them.

For example:
params.outdir = './out'


process COUNT {

    publishDir (
         path: "${params.outdir}/pipeline",
         mode: 'copy',
         saveAs: { filename ->
             "${filename.replaceFirst('_counts.csv', '')}/${filename}"
         }
    )

    output:
    path "*_counts.csv", emit: counts

    script:
    """
    touch project_{1,2,3}_counts.csv
    """
}

workflow {

    COUNT()
}

Results:
$ nextflow run main.nf 

 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.04.4

Launching `main.nf` [golden_booth] DSL2 - revision: 1be20c05ad

executor >  local (1)
[cd/5f5f96] process > COUNT [100%] 1 of 1 ✔

$ find out/ -type f
out/pipeline/project_3/project_3_counts.csv
out/pipeline/project_1/project_1_counts.csv
out/pipeline/project_2/project_2_counts.csv

Note that you can also set the publishDir directive in a configuration file, for example:
process {

    withName: 'COUNT' {

        publishDir = [
            path: { "${params.outdir}/pipeline" },
            mode: 'copy',
            saveAs: { filename ->
                "${filename.replaceFirst('_counts.csv', '')}/${filename}"
            }
        ]
    }
}

